# Probability of being at a given distance away from expected value

Tags: probability

I'm looking for the probability of being at a given distance away from expected value. Say I flip $2$ coins, if I get $2$ heads, I lose $1$ point; otherwise I win $1$ point. So the expected value is:

$(-1)(0.25)+(1)(0.75)=0.5$

How can I get the probability of being up $n$ points after repeating the experiment $m$ times?

I'm aware there are probably better terms and this should be quite a common problem, but I'm quite rusty when it comes to probability and I don't know where else to look for for this information. Can this be done only from EV, or do we need more information for this type of problem?

Comment: "probability of being up $n$ points" does not look the same as "at a given distance from expected value" to me...

Comment: I thought maybe this type of question could be answered with a Gaussian distribution centered at the expected value (independent axis would be n). As m->infinity, this distribution would become a delta function around the expected value. Then the distance from n (number of points) to the expected value is what I would be looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question properly, the solution involves binomial probabilities rather than the 
expectation you mentioned.

Call a trial a Success (S) if you gain 1 point (not HH),
so P(S) = 3/4. Call a trial a Failure (F) if you lose 1 point (HH),
so P(F) = 1/4.

If $X$ is the number of S's in $m$ trials, then $X \sim Bin(m, 3/4)$
and $P(X = k) = C(m, k)(3/4)^k(1/4)^{n-k},$ for $k = 0, \dots, m,$
where the binomial coefficient $C(a, b) = a!/[b!(a-b)!],$ for integers
$0 \le b \le a.$

Let $U$ be the number of points you are up, then $U = X - (m-X) = 2X-m.$
Notice that possible values of $U$ are alternate integers from $-m$ to $m$;
even values if $m$ is even and odd values if $m$ is odd.
$P(U = n) = P(X = (n+m)/2)$, for legal values of $n$.

Comment: Thanks, this is the result I was looking for for the specific example above. Is there a way to generalize this result based only on EV?

Comment: What I mean is: the example above seems to work only for the case where 2 situations are possible (+1 or -1). What if more than one situation was possible(i.e. HH=+2,HT=+1,TT=-1)? What about a distribution of payouts based on an arbitrary function?

Comment: Will be curious whether you post another version of this exploring more complex payoff structures.